# Help with /etc/fstab

Tags: server, fstab

I am trying to set up a nginx server on Ubuntu server 12.10 following [this tutorial](http://www.howtoforge.com/perfect-server-ubuntu-11.10-with-nginx-ispconfig-3-p5) and there is a section(16) about "/etc/fstab" that says:

> Edit /etc/fstab. Mine looks like this (I added ,usrjquota=quota.user,grpjquota=quota.group,jqfmt=vfsv0 to the partition with the mount point /):

I have no clue when it comes to operating system setup, so when I pasted that into my fstab file I knew I was going to have issues. My file looks like this:

[image: screenshot]

And the author of the tutorials fstab file is at the 16th section of the link above.

Also when I copy/pasted the info from the tutorial I got the following error messages:

[image: Error Message]

If you need anymore information I will gladly provide it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I just mistyped the file directory.

This line fixed it:

> /dev/md1 / ext4 grpjquota=quota.group,usrjquota=quota.user,jqfmt=vfsv1 0 2